# Having issues writing a new data file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a Python program that writes out 20 steps between 0 and 2*pi, with the value and the sin and cos of that value.

I have:

```
import math

f=open('question10.txt','w')
x=0
pi=math.pi
f.write("x, y=sin(x), z=cos(x)\n")
while x<=2*pi:
    f.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(x, math.sin(x), math.cos(x)))
    x = x+(pi/10)
f.close()
```

I have no idea what isn't working. It won't even create the data file, and isn't giving me any sort of error.

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe you're looking for the file in the wrong folder.

Comment: You're probably looking in the wrong folder, this code works for me.

Comment: Add `import os; print(os.getcwd())` - that is where your file will be.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use with instead of writing and closing directly. This will ensure that the file will be closed after writing without you having to manage it:

```
import math


x=0
pi=math.pi
with open("question10.txt", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write("x, y=sin(x), z=cos(x)\n")
    while x<=2*pi:
        out_file.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(x, math.sin(x), math.cos(x)))
        x = x+(pi/10)
```

If you are still having problems, perhaps you can explain the error you are encountering?

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. You should check that you run your python file correctly.